# What is the “purest” assembler or assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

For the past week or so, I've been attempting to learn the x86 assembly language on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine to gain a more intimate understanding of how a computer operates.

Unfortunately, I've made very little progress because many assemblers allow for the use of high-level constructs and macros and the inclusion of prewritten code. This wasn't a problem until I realized that all the documentation and tutorials I could find on the subject insist on using these abstractions, crutches, and obfuscations, which defeats my whole purpose of wanting to learn a truly low-level language.

So now I'm looking for a “pure” assembler or language, one without the bloat and cruft of a high-level assembly language and is as close to machine code as possible.

Comment: I'd say you have to dig deep in x86 documentation... Assembly is pretty architecture dependent, so I think the best way to find what is high level construct and what is not, is the processor documentation.

Comment: Which products have you tried?

Comment: I've tried FASM and NASM. I've looked at some other languages like MASM but they also employ these constructs.

Comment: NASM (and probably FASM) is perhaps the cleanest. It doesn't get in the way, you write what you want, no `ASSUME`, no `SOMETHING PTR`, etc. Of course, it won't catch some bugs that MASM and TASM would. But I think it's fair. I love it.

Comment: [YASM](http://yasm.tortall.net/) also accepts both NASM and AT&T (GAS) syntax (and thus requires no `ASSUME` nor `PTR`) and it also supports dwarf2 debug data format.

Comment: Just write a big program.  Believe me, you'll learn all about the low level machine instructions doing this.

Comment: Just because they *have* the constructs ("crutches") doesn't mean you have to *use* them. If you want "pure", get an old PC, run `debug` from the command line, and have at it. Or better yet, get an embedded system and a bare-bones assembler and have at it--there's more "bloat and cruft" surrounding everything Windows and x86 puts in your way than in anything an assembler offers.

Comment: If you dont already know asm or how the computer works x86 is the worst place to start.  Having the hardware is the number one worst excuse I have seen to use x86 first.  Start on a simulator, with a much better architecture.  You will have better visibility into what is going on as well as the benefits of a better instruction set,  down the road after you have learned a few other instruction sets then dive into x86 by going with old original 8088/8086 and working forward from there.   Start with msp430, pdp11, arm, thumb, avr then later mips then x86

Comment: start with one of msp430, pdp11, arm, thumb perhaps in reverse order or thumb (not thumb2 extensions) first then pdp11 (all of them have gnu support)

Comment: most assemblers (programs that convert assembly language into machine code) support the pure instruction set, you dont need all the junk that goes around it in order to use that tool.  less is more.

Answer (score 2):

Write your x86 machine code directly in a hex editor.

It's perfectly possible, I've done it plenty of times. But you will soon learn the value of those "abstractions, crutches and obfuscations", especially when you have to manually recalculate a jump offset for the 1000th time....

Comment: Hardly a useful answer. It's a big -- and completely unnecessary, in this case -- jump from writing instructions (without the extra stuff) to writing machine code.

Comment: OP wanted to understand the low level..... what else can I say?

Comment: I don't doubt the value of those constructs at all. They're useful, but I want to learn how a computer truly operates beneath those constructs. Rather than write in pure hex code, I'd rather create a dummy assembler in a higher-level language.

Comment: Sounds to me like nearly any assembler will do what you want. What you need is a tutorial that doesn't use any "crutches". Unfortunately, I don't know any to recommend. :(

Comment: Writing a program in a hex editor is as low as you're going to get unless you actually want to write it in 0's and 1's. Completely disagree with TJ. If you want to go as a low as possible and still be productive then this answer is correct. It's not completely unnecessary if the users goal is to learn. I learn to write shellcode for exploitation by writing directly in a hex editor. You'll learn so much from just doing it ... even if you "don't need" to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at NASM.

NASM has lots of higher level helper functions and macros that you can define, but you're completely at liberty to avoid using them.

One problem that you are likely to come into however is that assembly language compiles to bytes, but operating systems by and large don't run bytes, they run programs. Consequently you will almost certainly have to mess around with some of the higher level constructs in order to persuade whichever assembler you eventually settle on to generate a PE file (Windows) or an ELF file (Linux).

Comment: I can assemble code with NASM to ELF32 and then let gcc/ld (from MinGW) deal with the rest to get PE or ELF32.

Answer (score 2):

There are several levels of "pure". For example, when you use particular OS, you have to use its API in order to make input/output, memory allocations, etc. This API calls are provided by different ways - some of them easy, some of them not so easy.

For example, if you are working on Windows, you have to import functions from the system DLLs. But function import can not be considered "assembly programming".

The calling convention of these functions is C/C++/HLL so, you must use this calling convention, instead of more assembly-like.

So, you need at first OS, that to be assembly-friendly. I would suggest 32bit Linux - it uses int $80 and register parameters passing, so you will be able to concentrate on assembly language.

Here is very simple "hello world" example, written in FASM. As you can see, the overhead is very little and there is no any macros involved:

```
format ELF executable
entry _start

segment readable executable
_start:

        mov     eax, 4
        mov     ebx, 1
        mov     ecx, msg
        mov     edx, msg_size
        int     $80

        mov     eax, 1
        xor     ebx, ebx
        int     $80


segment readable writeable
msg db 'Hello world!',$0a
msg_size = $ - msg
```

Of course you will need some Linux system calls manual.  [Linux x86 Asm Software Development Kit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lscr/) is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

For pure assembly code, you can look at some basic hello world bootloaders. A bootloader doesn't rely on operating system calls but bios calls directly. You can take a look at this basic tutorial as an example, http://viralpatel.net/taj/tutorial/hello_world_bootloader.php. This is 16 bit assembly.